# Can someone else claim that their name should be on our paper because they have been working on the same problem?

Tags: publications, authorship, collaboration, research-misconduct

A few months ago, in our group meeting, my advisor brought up a problem in the field that might be interesting for us to think about it. Although it was not related to my PhD, since I was going for my defense, I started to think about it with another student and prepared a paper and sent it to the advisor. He saw it (one week before the deadline) and said that another student in the group (who was in that meeting) is also interested in that problem and is working on a simpler version of it with a totally different approach.

9 hours before the deadline of the paper submission, the guy who was working on the simpler version sent me a message and said that I have to add his name (and also his wife!) to our paper because he was working on the same problem and he wants his name to be on the first paper which is about that new problem. He said that in return, he will add my name and my collaborator's name to his paper (his wife is his collaborator in his paper, although her field was not related to the problem and that is why he asked for both names to be added in our paper). I didn't have any contribution in their paper and they didn't have in ours and I didn't even know what is in their paper.

I am the supervisor of our paper and adding another two PhD students to my paper (even if we could ignore the ethics!) vanishes my role in having supervision in all parts of the paper (including the code and results), and it was really hard for me. I said that I cannot do it and we will submit our papers and see what will happen. In my whole research time, this never happened to me and it is so weird to me that why I shouldn't say no and face such complaints.

I did ask my advisor about this. He said that it was our fault that we didn't communicate about our projects, but he is okay if we want to exchange the names.

Did I do something wrong? Would you please suggest the right answer for such requests? Can he annoy me in the future?

Comment: Reply to his message with a simple "no"

Comment: This question should be tagged 'cheating'.

Comment: This is unbelievable. Of course, you did nothing wrong. Which cannot be said about the other student. He has no right to annoy you and judging from his poor communication and behaviour, we can just wish that he won’t cross your path academically anymore.

Comment: Thanks @Jan. I really hope so. It was a lot of pressure, more than what I expected.

Comment: I think I'll start working on the Riemann hypothesis. Not that I have any hope of solving it, but if anyone else succeeds I'll demand that they put my name on their paper.

Answer (score 75):

Working in parallel isn't collaboration. Unless the other people contributed directly to your paper then they have no right to authorship. Nor would you have right to authorship of theirs. It would be pure "gift" authorship, a form of misconduct in many (not all) fields.

Actually, though, your supervisor should have managed this better so that you didn't come to such a point within a single group. Parallel research and having someone else scoop you is bad enough (for individuals) in the general case, but it shouldn't happen in a single research group.

I don't know what you can manage politically in this situation, but the ethics are clear. Hopefully you all have something to contribute.

Comment: Re: "in many (not all) fields." I would be curious to know in which fields gift authorship is *not* a form of misconduct...

Comment: @AlbertoSantini There are some fields where gifting authorship to your supervisor is the norm.

Comment: @NickS Please name one explicitly.

Comment: @NickS a supervisor bringing you into a project that gives you funding, providing you a research theme, shaping the questions you answered with a publication is not being gifted a publication, such a supervisor is being recognized for the necessary steps they directly did in producing the research presented in the paper, even if they did not write one single character in the paper, they were directly involved in the results obtained (and it is very dissimilar than simply giving the code, or selling the code, or discussing the results at a conference/workshop...).

Comment: Gift authorship is immoral.

Comment: @EarlGrey Well, in my field (pure mathematics) what you describe would be considered gift authorship. My supervisor did all that, and only expected an Aknowledgement.. The papers where he was an author were papers where I did some of the proofs and he did other proofs.... I do understand that in my field we are lucky that the costs are low, we do not need large funds for experiments, and getting the funding can be essential to projects, but also I know from experience/discussions that this creates a very grey area some supervisors push/cross.

Comment: As a (former) physicist, every time I read comments here I am amazed and somewhat appalled at the way the authorship culture apparently works in pure mathematics. It's unthinkable to me to equate including the supervisor as an author with "gift authorship", if they contributed resources, direction, discussions, framing the research questions, interpretation of results, etc. I understand different fields work differently, but still it seems like there must be a lot of fighting for credit in that field.

Comment: @Andrew, actually, I never saw any such fighting for credit. It is just a convention that students in pure math are sole authors of their dissertations. Students don't usually work in teams and are usually funded as TAs, not under grants, so it is just an understanding in the field. I worked in CS after changing fields but would not have considered assuming an authorship position with my students, even though I gave direction, etc. I agree that math may err a bit in the opposite direction but it works in practice.

Comment: @Andrew, Professional mathematicians help one another quite a lot, but, unless they start out on a joint project, don't worry much about authorship even for some key advice, though it might actually be deserved. Applied math, like the sciences, has different customs.

Comment: @Andrew I have never had a fight for credit. My summer salary came from his grant, but otherwise would had came from the department, does this deserve authorship? Discussions? Well we freely discuss our projects in our field, and gave ideas (some which worked, some which didn't) but never expected anything beyond an aknowledgement for this. And this is likely the reason why people feel so free to discuss ideas/proofs, if authorship was expected for every single discussion or idea then people would start guarding the projects. Interpretation of resuts, what's that ;)....

Comment: ... Now, where things could get tricky is the "framing of research question" and "direction", because if someone gives me a clear problem and the key ideas for the proofs, even if I end up filling in the missing details and write the paper, in my oppinion their contribution is already bigger than mine....For many math projects, the idea of the proof for the main theorems is the main contribution....But for other math projects, the "research question" can be something vague or even coming from the student itself (not often but not uncommon either)...

Comment: @NickS getting the funding is not easy. To get fundings you need to write a proposal, with a deep scientific knowledge of the state of the art, you need to substantiate it, you need to clearly define goals and questions you will answer with the research, sometimes even pass oral examinations. Let's not downplay the "getting funds" part: today it is extremely hard, it is not anymore that a professor or a supervisor has automatically funds for postdocs and phds.

Comment: @NickS please write down at least one field where "gifting authorship to your supervisor is the norm. "

Comment: @EarlGrey I do hold a grant, so I know exactly what it takes. Now, if I pay a student RA stippends from my grant, give them a problem and some rough ideas for how to approach it, have weekly meeting with them for discussions and help them with revisions of manuscript I do NOT expect authorship.... I am just doing my job as supervisor, and in my field authorship in this situation is "gift authorship"...  I am only expecting authorship when I need to start producing some of the proofs in the project, and trully contributing towards it (typically doing multiple proofs).

Comment: @NickS you made it clear what is (according to you and your archaic field) gift authorship, what is relevant is in which field is gifting authorship the norm (since you mentioned there are fields where it is common, write down explicitly).

Comment: @EarlGrey Note that what is considered gift authorshipin my field (see previous comment) is the norm in other fields. As far as I remember in CS, Physics,  Chemestry just to name a few, funding+set up clear problem+regular meetings+proofreading the final manuscript is usually enough to grant the supervisor authorship...

Comment: @EarlGrey, wow, interesting how you are *appalled* (literally raging) that some fields hold their senior academics to stricter ethical standards than your former field, a bit similar to how some people are outraged at vegans.

Comment: In general I'm amazed how people list "providing funding/resources" as a ground for authorship as if there were nothing wrong with it. A supervisor is not *providing funding*, he's managing it on behalf of the funding body. Demanding authorship in exchange for a decision made in that capacity is as wrong as it gets; much worse than just "guest authorship".

Comment: @Kostya_I "*A supervisor is not providing funding, he's managing it on behalf of the funding body"*. This is at best an offensive downplaying of the efforts required to write proposals, at worst a clear misunderstanding of how funding works in the current state of things ...

Comment: @EarlGrey, sure, it's a lot of effort, so what? It's an effort spent competing for the right to manage public money, akin to running for an office. But after you get that right, it's still public money, and demanding bribes or personal favors in exchange for allocating it is literally a crime. An authorship which otherwise would not be warranted is clearly an example of such personal favor.

Comment: @Kostya_I I agree on the philosophical level of the public money being allocated to researchers. Unfortunately in reality there is already someone managing the public funds, so the researcher receiving them has no responsibility on them (see the numerous examples of public money badly spent in research) and they are simply spending them. Additionally, your point is moot when the research money is coming from a private institution (I do not understand how the hypothetical exchange money4publication is not corruption with private money, btw).

Comment: @EarlGrey, PI have a lot of say in how to spend it, such as whom to hire, what to procure, and certainly can be liable for corruption. My point is that if something is *prima facie* illegal, it's hard to make a case that it is ethical. The private money edge case only strengthens the argument against the "he provided funding" authorship: suppose one of the authors is a philantropist who funded but did not participate in the research - I think most would consider authorship inappropriate.

Comment: @Kostya_I You are welcome to address your points to the  CS, Physics, Chemistry communities (just to name a few) where funding+set up clear problem+regular meetings+proofreading the final manuscript is usually enough to grant the supervisor authorship.
I am sure that there archaic point of views, where the scientists are heremits whose purity from society and social dynamics can be preserved: very good for them, I let them enjoy their ivory tower.

Comment: @EarlGrey I'm not sure what should I ask. I can read, e.g., the APS or ACS guidelines, and they are both pretty clear that what you describe does not merit authorship. I also would receive a lot of answers from people engaged in this kind of activity vehemently assuring me that because they do it, it is ethical, which is of no value.

Comment: @Kostya_I you are referring to some societies, have a look at the comment from https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/182917/can-someone-else-claim-that-their-name-should-be-on-our-paper-because-they-have/182918?noredirect=1#comment491594_182918 , I have no personal connection to these communities.

Answer (score 18):

> Did I do something wrong? Would you please suggest the right answer for such requests? Can he annoy me in the future?

You did not do anything wrong. In your life people will often make unreasonable requests of you. Learning to say “no” is a useful skill, and one of the elements of that skill is the knowledge that [“no” is a complete sentence](https://www.mindful.org/no-is-a-complete-sentence/). That is, the right answer for such requests is simply “no”. A more polite version of this will read something along the lines of:

> Hi [name],
>
> It’s nice that you also found the problem interesting and are working on a paper about it. About your question, I do not need to be a coauthor on your paper, and am not interested in adding you as a coauthor on mine. Thanks for the suggestion though. And good luck with your conference submission.
>
> Regards,
> user137927

Comment: I think it would be better to explain why you are saying no - as Buffy said, the reason is that the other person didn't contribute - rather than just saying "no" on its own or "I am not interested in adding you."

Comment: @gib when the request is very unreasonable (as this one clearly is) it is often better not to explain the reason for the “no”. That is a key point of the “no is a complete sentence” principle.

Comment: But the person making the request is a student and probably doesn't understand that it is unreasonable

Comment: @gib sometimes the best way to help someone understand something is to let them think about it and figure it out for themselves. Regardless, OP has no responsibility to help the other person understand anything.

Comment: The best way to help the person in this case would be to tell them the reason, which would only take a few seconds. If people only helped others when they had a professional responsibility to do so, the world would be a much worse place.

Comment: @gib sure, and if people didn’t write comments that contain an obvious straw man fallacy, the world would be a better place. It’s pretty clear I wasn’t advocating for “only helping others when you had a professional responsibility to do so”. That’s your interpretation, which I reject.

Comment: @gib >>probably doesn't understand ... "in return, I offer you an author spot on my paper"  Yep, the other student understands.

Comment: @Dan Romik It wasn't a straw man argument, it was a general statement, just intended to imply that I think OP should be helpful to the other person, even if they do not have a professional responsibility to do so. I stick to what I said in my first comment.

Comment: @mcalex Yes that part does look suspicious, but they are a student so I still think they probably don't understand the issues.

Comment: @gib they understand enough to think "two wrongs makes one right". A clear no will stop their brain&heart wandering into the realms of unethical things.

Comment: @DanRomik I see no harm in including a sentence of explanation here, while I do see possible harm in omitting it. Why do you still prefer the latter?

Comment: @Neinstein there is a type of person who won’t take no for an answer, and offer objections to any explanation you offer them, requiring you to clarify your explanation, which they will then refute again, and so on ad infinitum. Arguing with them is exhausting and pointless. After you go through this a few times you learn that in some situations just saying “no” without giving any opening for debate is the best way forward, for both sides. This is one of those situations IMO. But if OP wants to give an explanation and see where that takes them, then sure, they’re not risking very much.

Comment: +1 to Dan's point above. In fact, these comments present a fair example of the possible give-reasons trap.

Comment: The "trap" is avoided by giving the reason *once*, and then refusing to engage further. That way, you educate someone who honestly doesn't know better (which is, sadly, possible), without falling victim to any traps, help-vampirism, or extended discussions.

Comment: @CodyGray if only it were that simple. My point is that if you give an explanation N times and then refuse to engage further, for any value of N greater than 0, the type of person I was referring to will come away very angry because in their mind you gave them N completely invalid explanations, each one more invalid and dishonest than the previous one, and then abruptly cut off the debate, probably because you couldn’t face their overwhelmingly convincing rebuttal arguments. N=0 is the only value that avoids this effect. This has been my experience at least.

Answer (score 14):

Well, this is a mess.  Normally, **people in the same research group are supposed to collaborate and keep each other informed** of what they're doing.  Clearly, that failed pretty badly here, and I'd say the fault is shared by you and your advisor:

- You say that the initial meeting where your advisor brought up the problem was a few months ago.  It's not clear how long after the meeting you started working on the problem, but presumably it was at least several weeks ago.  At that point, you should've told your advisor what you were working on, and preferably also informed other group members directly e.g. in a group meeting.
- Even though your advisor apparently only found out about your project when you sent them your finished paper a week before the submission deadline, they should still have arranged an *immediate* meeting between you and the other student(s) working on the same problem, instead of waiting for the deadline to pass.
- That said, given that your advisor didn't arrange such an emergency meeting, *you* should've taken it upon yourself to immediately contact the other student and discuss the issue.
- More generally, the fact that this whole chain of events came to pass makes it seem like communication and collaboration within your research group is pretty dysfunctional.  While good teamwork is part of everyone's job, ultimately the team leader — i.e. your advisor — is responsible for ensuring that it happens.

---

As for the issue of "exchanging authorship" at hand, I agree with the other answers that you *technically* did the right thing here by refusing it, since the other student (and his wife) hadn't actually contributed anything to your paper.

That said, I would say that you also did the wrong thing in letting events get to that point in the first place.  Ideally, you would've informed your advisor when you started working on the problem, and they would've arranged for you and the other student to work together, so that the resulting paper(s) would indeed have enough contribution from both of you to justify coauthorship.

Also, by refusing the offer, there's a risk that you may have made an enemy — possibly a life-long one.

The other student almost certainly didn't see their offer of "exchanged authorship" as inappropriate under the circumstances, or they wouldn't have made it in the first place.  As such, they're not likely to take your "no" reply as "no, that would be inappropriate", but rather as "no, we don't want to work together with you, we'd rather just scoop you and take all the credit, f*** you very much".

That said, there may not be much you can do about that now.  An honest face-to-face talk with the other student might help, especially if you start by admitting that you screwed up by not involving them in your work earlier, and that you do genuinely want to collaborate with them in the future.  Or not, but at least you can say that you tried.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I agree with you. I didn't know what they are working on. When they asked me to exchange the names, I immediately said that in the future I will provide all of our codes and results to help them, but can't add their name because I spent so much time on it. But he said it is the first work with this problem and it is important to him to be their name in it. I even asked if they have published something before, we can cite it, but he said that he had planned to submit it to conferences but for some reason missed it. The only choice he left was adding the names.

Comment: I absolutely didn't know what to do at 3 AM, 9 hours before the deadline. I cannot even say that our work is better than theirs. None of us knows what is in the other paper. But it seems that my advisor said to them that our work is good and it makes them angry. Although my advisor several times said that they are not interested in our approach at all and their approach in PhD is totally different. The only problem they had was being the first one who propose a method for the problem.

Comment: You could have added the alternate approach to your paper as an addendum of sorts, and then you guys could happily be co-authors on the resulting paper. But 9 hours before the deadline makes that genuinely impossible. Maybe alluding to an alternate approach being worked on by another member of your group and mentioning them as (x. xx, unpublished observations) would have worked, and left the other approach as something much less likely to get scooped by others in the future.

Comment: This. There would have been one more potential "rescue point": whereever that deadline came from, deciding to let that deadline go would have gained the group time to resolve the mess, sleep over the trouble and then calmly sit together and decide on a strategy for the paper(s). Be it one big paper with all authors, two papers with actual contributions from all authors, two papers with the original crews respectively submitted at the same time to the same journal with a cover letter explaining that there are two independent papers, or even something else.

Comment: @user137927 Both approaches Tamoghna suggested would've been the ideal solutions. But as he said, these simply weren't plausible 9 hours before the deadline. *This is not your fault*: the other student should've contacted you in time, or the supervisor should've told him about your work in time. It's unreasonable to expect the author to  make such changes within such a short timeframe.

Comment: @Neinstein: I'd say it _is_ the OP's fault to some degree, because they could've and should've told their advisor that they were working on the problem sooner, instead of leaving it until the paper was fully written and there was just one week until the submission deadline. But in general, apportioning blame is not a very productive exercise — it's better to discuss together what everyone involved can do to prevent the problem from happening again, whether it was their fault or not.